# Martingale and $E[X_{n+2} | F_n]$

Tags: probability

I don't reach to understand why if $(X_n)$ is a martingale for the filtration $(F_n)$, then  $E[X_{n+2} \lvert F_n]= X_n$.

Thank you in advance for the consideration to this message,

Comment: $E(X_{n+2}|F_{n})=E(E(X_{n+2}|F_{n+1})|F_{n})$ by tower law.